# Configure htaccess to show index.php as the default page instead of permissions error

Tags: htaccess, apache

Having a problem with my *.htaccess*. I have this to secure all my documents:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Now everything works fine except that the index page of `www.mysite.com` doesn't work and gives me the notification:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

How can you fix this?
If there stands `www.example.com/index.php` it works but if you surf to `www.example.com` I get this message.

Answer (score 1):

You have told Apache to allow for these extensions, but I'd say you didn't tell it to use another default page than `index.html`.  Perhaps you should add something like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to your configuration?